# Find free resolution of ideal $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

> If we consider the ideal $I=(x,y)$ as a module over the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, how can we find a free resolution of $I$?

That is, a sequence $$...P_2 \to P_1 \to P_0 \to I \to 0$$ with $P_i$ free and the sequence being exact. I dont know how one in general constructs free resolution so I have just been brute-forcing. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x,y)$ is a regular sequence in $R=\mathbf Q[x,y]$ , hence the Koszul complex:
\begin{alignat*}{3}0\longrightarrow R&\xrightarrow{\begin{bmatrix}x\!&\!\!y\end{bmatrix}} R^2&\xrightarrow{\smash[t]{\begin{bmatrix}-y\\x\end{bmatrix}}}&R\longrightarrow R/(x,y)\longrightarrow 0 \\
t&\longmapsto \rlap{(xt, yt)}\\
&(u,v)&\longmapsto & -uy+vx
\end{alignat*}
is a free resolution of $R/(x,y)$, hence you have a free resolution of the kernel of the last non-zero map:
$$
0\longrightarrow R\xrightarrow{\begin{bmatrix}x\! &\!\!y\end{bmatrix}}  R^2\xrightarrow {\smash[t]{\begin{bmatrix}-y\\x\end{bmatrix}}}(x,y)\longrightarrow 0 $$

Comment: Thank you. Can you improve your answer a little, since I am not familiar with this. For example, how does the map $R^2 \to R$ look like? It maps the tuple $(a,b)$ to the product? I dont understand the last part, how is it a free resolution of the ideal, should it be $R$ or $I$ in the entry before $0$?

Comment: @kali_ghana: I added some details. Is it clearer? Note the image of the morphism $\;\mathbf R^2\rightarrow\mathbf R$ is the ideal $(x,y)$.